# How do you use datatables ajax function

Tags: datatables

How do you use the [following](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)?

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('dataTablesData') )
    );
  }
} );
```

When i try to apply it to my application, I'm trying to call a function that holds json but i keep getting `callback is not a function`

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      JSON.parse( sessionStorage.accInfoCookie )
    );
  }
} );
```

How do I use a function with the datatables ajax? Can someone provide a simple working example please?

Comment: The above is "AJAX" using an alternative source, is that what you want? What version of dataTables are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.10.12. I've been able to make simple working examples for all other datatables ajax examples on the page referenced above except the one in question. So i'm looking for help with the exact syntax above, not a completely different method like the first answer posted by Stallion. So the big thing will probably be figuring out how to get past `callback is not a function` to make it work.

Comment: It works out of the box for me, "_callback is not a function_" is a little bit strange since you never need to define it yourself, you simply just call callback with a JSON src.  I believe something else is breaking the flow, but it will need a overview of the entire setup to target out.

Comment: You're right, it was something else in my code that I didn't see before. once i corrected the offending issues, the issue for this went away.

Answer (score 0):

use "usersView" as id in table tag. And below is the script.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
    $('#usersView').DataTable({
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bInfo": false,
        'pageLength': 20,
        "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{'bSortable': false}],
        "aaSorting": []
    });
})
</script>
```